# Find Last Chosen Day of a Chosen Month

Tags: excel, date, find, dayofweek

I have this code which allows me to find the first or last given day of the given month.

=DATE(B2,A2,1+7*n)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B2,A2,8-xday))

- B2 = Year
- A2 = Month
- n = do I the want to find the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, or 5th occurrence
- xday = is a number representing the day of the week (1 = Sun through to 7 = Sat)

I want something which will find only the last given day of the given month without me having to figure out whether the month has 4 or 5 Mondays.

If someone can show me how to create the result I want in VBA that would be perfect.

Comment: Does it _have_ to be VBA?  Because this is pretty easy to do with a worksheet formula: `=IF(DATE(B2,D4,36)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B2,D4,8-xday))<DATE(B2,D4+1,1),DATE(B2,D4,36)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B2,D4,8-xday)),DATE(B2,D4,29)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B2,D4,8-xday)))`

Comment: You already have right formula to find it. Simply look for zeroth occurance in `A2+1` month.

Comment: @Adam - This is what I wanted, however it doesnt work when I enter the months of March(3) June (6) August(8) or November (11), seems to return NAME# when i enter any of those. Please provide a fix. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my Question thanks to @Dave & edited by me is:

```
=IF(DATE(B2,D4,36)-DAY(DATE(B2,D4,8-xday))<DATE(B2,D4+1,1),DATE(B2,D4,36)-DAY(DATE(B2,D4,8-xday)),DATE(B2,D4,29)-DAY(DATE(B2,D4,8-xday)))
```

Where:

- B2 = Year
- D4 = Month (1-12)
- Xday = Day (1-7)

Answer (score 1):

For this data layout,

[image: Last weekday in eomonth]

The formula in D2 is,

```
=EOMONTH(A$2,0)-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(A$2,0)-C2)*(WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(A$2,0))<>C2)
```

C2:C8 and c11:C17 are simply 1->7 formatted as *ddd*.

The VBA for that would be something like this for last Tuesday (weekday **3**) in August.

```
dim lastDate as date
'last Tue in Aug-2015
lastDate = dateserial(2015, 9, 0)-abs(weekday(dateserial(2015, 9, 0)-3)*(weekday(dateserial(2015, 9, 0))<>3))
debug.print lastDate
'last Sat in Jul-2015
lastDate = dateserial(2015, 8, 0)-abs(weekday(dateserial(2015, 8, 0)-7)*(weekday(dateserial(2015, 8, 0))<>7))
debug.print lastDate
```

Note that VBA shortcut for the worksheet [EOMONTH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EOMONTH-function-7314FFA1-2BC9-4005-9D66-F49DB127D628) is simply the zero day of the next month. The [Abs function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262673(v=vs.60).aspx) is necessary as VBA treats True as -1, not 1 like a worksheet.